# CSS - Dynamic Div minimum / maximum position

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a div containing the website logo, that I stuck in the top left corner of my website.
In order to have it dynamic, I put its position on a 10% screenwidth from the left. Now the problem occurs when the browser gets smaller than the width of my content, it obscures important buttons or text on the website.

I cant seem to figure out how to resolve this and any input would be great.
Edit: added additional divs to contain both the Logo banner and the Login-menu above the website;

Header.php:

```
    <div id="navcontainer" class="navcontainer-div">
      <div id="bannier" class="bannier-div">
         <a href="http://webstore.thelifeforge.nl"><img src='/img/banner.png'></a>
      </div> 
      <div id="navigation" class="navigation-div">
         <table width='100%'>menu content</table>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Style.css:

```
.navcontainer-div
{
    margin-left:-10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    width:100%;
    /*height: 125px; 
    background-color: #AEB861;*/
    background-image: url('/img/header_bg.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    display:block;  
    border-radius: 3px;
    top:0;
    position: fixed;
}

.navigation-div
{
    z-index: 2;
    max-width:1000px;
    height:60px;
    background-color: #E4EEB9;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.bannier-div
{
    z-index: 3;
    left:10%;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:150px;
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot to see the problem?

Comment: @JamieButtonsCoulter A good live example of what I have running now is on the 'store' section of my website; http://webstore.thelifeforge.nl/store.php

Comment: Do you want the logo to always be the same size?

Comment: In an ideal scenario, the Logo scales down to a minimum size and slides into the top bar next to the "Turning Fantasy into a Reality" text.
But I havent figured that out yet, so for now I take what I can get haha!

Comment: I think in this case you are going to need quite a lot of changes to your markup

Comment: Yeah probably. I havent touched HTML, PHP or CSS in over 3 years and i am trying to find my footing again, haha!
Also I updated the original post to reflext the header flow a bit better, perhaps this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should user another class or id with parent element.

Example:

At page http://webstore.thelifeforge.nl/about.php we have id navigation

At page http://webstore.thelifeforge.nl don't have id navigation

So we can write:

```
.bannier-div
{
    z-index: 3;
    left:10%;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:150px;
}

#navigation .bannier-div
{
    z-index: 3;
    left:5%;
    position: fixed;
    width:100%;
    max-width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Alright, I see how we can add custom CSS by creating these differences in the code. However, what do I do about the positioning in this case?
Because left: 5%; will still cause an overlap at a certain point.